# what am I doing wrong while trying to add not null to one of the columns

Tags: postgresql

I have tried adding not null constraint in one of the learning exercises on freecodecamp but it keeps on giving me this error:

```
universe=> alter table galaxy alter column size integer not null;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "integer"
LINE 1: alter table galaxy alter column size integer not null;
                                             ^
universe=> alter table galaxy alter column size shortint not null;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "shortint"
LINE 1: alter table galaxy alter column size shortint not null;
```

The mentioned table galaxy is created and has values in it already and the column 'size' exists as well. I cannot figure out why am I getting this error

Tried all the alter table and column commands, modify column command but nothing worked. I was expecting to add not null constraint on one of the columns.

Comment: Sorry I am new to sql and the website. So didn't really know about that. I'll keep that in mind for next time

Comment: What is the current type for the column `size`?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a PostgreSQL message. In PostgreSQL you need to apply the type change and the not-null constraint change in separate statements, e.g.:

```sql
create table galaxy ( size integer );
alter table galaxy alter column size TYPE integer;
alter table galaxy alter column size SET not null;
```

Comment: No it does not need to be separate statements: `alter table galaxy alter column size TYPE integer, alter column size SET not null;`